# How do I copy something into the parent directory of my build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradlew

How can I copy FileA into Dir2? Assuming FileA is created with a gradle build?

```
Parent
- Gradle Proj
    - build.gradle
    - FileA
-Dir2
-Dir3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own task to do so

```
task copyDocs(type: Copy) {
    from './fileA'
    into './Dir2'
}
tasks.named("build") { finalizedBy("copyDocs") }
```

This will do the copy when the task named "build" is finished .

And you can also use the `afterEvaluation` i think . For more info about you can check [the official docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:project_evaluation) .

for example

```
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        task copyDocs(type: Copy) {
            from './fileA'
            into './Dir2'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I managed to find $rootDir which targets the root directory of the project.

This made it easy to copy eg:

```
task copyDocs(type: Copy) {
    from '$projectDir/FileA'
    into '$rootDir/Dir2'
}
```